# Android - Call a method every millisecond without using Threads

Tags: java, android, multithreading, hashmap

**The problem**

I have a `Map<Long, String>`

I need to start a timer, and when the time (in milliseconds) matches any of the keys in the Map, It should append its value to a TextView.

**What I have tried**

I have already tried implementing **Timer** and **Handler**, but as both of them use Threads, the output gets misarranged.

```
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (map.containsKey(elapsed)) {
                        textView.append(map.get(elapsed));
                    }
                }
            });
            elapsed++;
        }
    }, 0, 1);
```

**What I need**

A way to get it done without using Threads. The main issue here is because the code has to be executed every millisecond, threads mess up and the chars get misarranged. Is there any efficient way of achieving the desired result?

Comment: use a while loop.... why do you need it to always run? seems like an awful way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

First-  If you're looking to run something every milliseconds, find a different OS.  Android (and Linux in gneneral) are not optimized for that kind of operation.  You really need an RTOS to assure that will work.  Linux's sleep command doesn't even honor an argument that small, it will default to a no-op for it.

Secondly-  you probably don't actually want it to run every millisecond.  You're almost definitely massively over estimating the frequency it needs to be done with.

Third-  you're writing to a UI.  The UI only updates every 1/60th of a second at a maximum rate.  So even if you got it running at 1ms it wouldn't do anything more than 60 times a second (about 16ms).

Fourth-  the answer is Thread.  Not Threads-  a single thread.  That runs a while loop sleeping for a ms between attempts (although a sleep for 1ms is likely just to return immediately, or to return at whatever the timer frequency of the system is, likely 16 ms).  But you wouldn't want one thread per request, you'd want one thread period, so the attempts occurs synchronously and don't depend on thread scheduling.

But the real answer is that the way you're doing things is wrong, and you should be approaching things from a different direction.

Comment: Re, "Linux's sleep command..." In recent versions of Linux, the primitive system call is `nanosleep(...)`, and [its man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html) says that the requested interval will be rounded _up_ to the nearest multiple of the system clock period. In other words, a Linux program that asks to sleep for one millisecond will be guaranteed to sleep for _at least_ one millisecond... Not that that helps the OP any.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you can achieve this:

Use Handler: Using Handler does not necessarily require creating another thread. You can create a handler to use the UI thread's looper/messagequeue and keep calling "postDelayed" on it by delaying whatever time you want.

Use AlarmManager: You can use "setRepeating" to schedule a PendingIntent sending repeatedly. Mind that AlarmManager will not be exact post API 19 though